# How to use textbox to search data in data grid view

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

Imagine that you have a table and you want to filter any type of data. I want to appear the entire line relates to this value, for example, date, Name, Description, Value by only filter 1 table field

```
string filter = "";
string command = "SELECT * FROM Movimentos WHERE [Tipo de Movimento] = 'Crédito'";


if (textDataMovimento.Text != "")
{
    filter = filter + "[Data Movimento] LIKE '%" + textDataMovimento.Text + "%' AND";
}
if (textDataValor.Text != "")
{
    filter = filter + " [Data Valor] LIKE '%" + textDataValor.Text + "%' AND";
}
if (textDescricao.Text != "")
{
    filter = filter + " [Descrição] LIKE '%" + textDescricao.Text + "%' AND";
}
if (textValor.Text != "")
{
    filter = filter + " [Valor] LIKE '%" + textValor.Text + "%' AND";
}
if (textTipodeMovimento.Text != "")
{
    filter = filter + "[Tipo de Movimento] LIKE  '%" + textTipodeMovimento.Text + "%'AND";
}
```

Comment: Care of SQL Injection, use parameters instead

Comment: Im here to looking for help , im new using this language , working on it only about a couple of days

Comment: Just pass your parameters to your query and use `ISNULL(Param, Column)` this way you don't need to check if text boxes is empty or not. To be honest I dunno about C#. The filter property will be hard cause you will need to check every textbox to put `AND` or not, just use the query parameters.

Comment: I refer to the comment I made on your other post (on a different account?): *"What you're after is [SqlCommand.Parameters Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8). Parametrisation of SQL commands is incredibly important. If you're not familiar with it, I suggest have a read up on [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)."*

Comment: Also you miss `AND` in the final of `"SELECT * FROM Movimentos WHERE [Tipo de Movimento] = 'Crédito'"`. Imagine that only `textDataMovimento.Text != ""` is true, then the query will be `"SELECT * FROM Movimentos WHERE [Tipo de Movimento] = 'Crédito' [Data Movimento] LIKE '%valueoftextbox%' AND"` which is invalid and will throw an error.

Comment: Truthfully, considering that this is a "kitchen sink" or "catch-all" query, then this would likely be better solved by using dynamic SQL, and **parametrisation**. [#BackToBasics: An Updated "Kitchen Sink" Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) & [Catch-all Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/).

Answer (score 0):

Some hopefully helpful hints although I  don't think that these will be the answer you want they should give you some guidance on good application design ...

1. Never mix UI code with data layer code (look in to N-Tier Architectures)
2. SQL Injection should be avoided perhaps consider using an ORM
3. Binding your controls to objects should be preferrable to direct data values from the DB (read up on "separation of concerns".

Something that might be closer to your intended goal though ...

Consider using something like "LINQ to SQL" ... it allows your C# to be C# and the underlying framework will handle your query generation against the database in a "safe" manner.

As for the actual binding of data to the grid in order to render the results consider some of these options ...

https://www.google.com/search?q=binding+a+datagrid+view+to+an+object+collection

...

**Final Note**

I realise that this may raise more questions for you and may not be the intention but there's a lot to cover about this implementation that I feel needs to be raised in order that you improve the way you use this technology so as to avoid common pitfalls in software development.

Answer (score -1):

Simply prepare a dynamic sql raw query to search the matching row with respect to matching column values.

Note: never use parameter values directly in the raw query, always use the sql parameters to pass the values. This helps on avoiding sql injection.